# Automatically add a schedule from Google Sheets into Calendar using options to repeat daily, weekly, or monthly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have been working on some code to automatically schedule multiple events from a google sheet into a google calendar that includes the title, date, and options for repeating events (daily, weekly, monthly). In other words, for each event input into the sheet, I want the option to type or select if each event will repeat daily, weekly, or monthly.

Counseling, 2/10/2022, Monthly

Tutoring, 2/10/2022, Weekly

Everything works as far as scheduling the event in Calendar; however, it does not set the event to repeat. Is there a way to to indicate on the sheet how you would like the event to repeat, that then syncs to the Calendar? This is where I am with the code:

```
    function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Sync Now', 'scheduleSafetyPlan')
      .addToUi();
    }
    
function scheduleSafetyPlan() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var spreadsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Safety Plan");
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("F1").getValues();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:D15").getValues();

  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
    
    var shift = signups[x];
   
    var title = shift[0];
    var startDate = shift[1];
    var recurrence = shift[2];
    if (title && startDate && recurrence) {
    eventCal.createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, recurrence);
    
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal from `I want the option to type or select if each event will repeat daily, weekly, or monthly.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: No Problem! I can't get "recurrence" to work. The code works to sync the event title, start date, to the calendar, but I can't figure out how to indicate how I want the event to repeat on the calendar. Some events will be daily, some weekly, and some monthly. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: The code I have above successfully schedules the event with a title and start date, but does not produce recurring events.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your goal from `The code I have above successfully schedules the event with a title and start date, but does not produce recurring events.`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.